# How to combine button in imageview in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-imageview

i want to make app like smart home app. But i face some problem, on of them is how to make the sketch combine with button, so if the light button (yellow icon) pressed then will show up "the light was on".

Sketch of house with button:

[image]

Anyone can help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to assign a **selector** (state list drawable) to the `src`  attribute of the `ImageView`.

eg:

The `your_selector_xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_yellow_lamp"
        android:state_focused="true" />

    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_yellow_lamp"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_default_lamp" />

</selector>
```

Your `ImegeView`

```
<ImageView 
     ....
     android:src="@drawable/your_selector_xml"/>
```

Comment: but where i put the sketch image ?

Comment: In *drawable/* file.

Comment: so in <ImageView, i set the andorid:background="@drawable/sketch" ?
then how i can match the position of the lamp into the room? So it will not move

Comment: In <ImageView, you need to use the selector.xml as *andorid:background* or *andorid:scr* . You can use a RelativeLayout as parent layout then you place your sketch-ImageViews inside, depending on the room position.

Comment: but when i try to install to another device, the design is not same when i design it first, how i can fix that?
thanks